# Combine jquery form validation and django internationalization

Tags: jquery, django, forms, internationalization

I am working in a project where we have 2 languages, and I validate a form with jquery. Everything works fine, except I am not able to translate the error messages for the form. I have tried using {% trans %} and sending the message as a context variable already translated with ugettext, but neither worked. There sure must be a way to do it. Any help would be great, thanks!

Code:

```js
var formValid = {mail_num_valid: false, name_valid: false};

function checkValidation() {
if (formValid.mail_num_valid == true && formValid.name_valid == true) {

  $('#submitButton').removeAttr("disabled");
} else {

  $('#submitButton').attr("disabled", "true");
}
};

$('#{{ form.mail_or_num.id_for_label }}').on('input', function() {
var mail_num = $(this).val();


function msg(content) {
  $('#mail_num_error').text(content).show();
};

function hide() {
  $('#mail_num_error').hide();
};

var num_exp = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$'); 
var mail_exp = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/

num_test = num_exp.test(mail_num);
mail_test = mail_exp.test(mail_num);



if (mail_test) {
  formValid.mail_num_valid = true;
  hide();

}

else if(mail_num.length == 0) {
  formValid.mail_num_valid = false;
  hide();
}

else if (num_test && 9 <= mail_num.length && mail_num.length <= 13) {   
  formValid.mail_num_valid = true;
  hide();

}

else if (mail_num.length < 5) {
  msg({% trans 'Too short to be a valid mail or number' %}); // This sends an error.
  formValid.mail_num_valid = false;
}

else if (num_test && mail_num.length < 9) {
    msg("The number is too short");
    formValid.mail_num_valid = false;
  }

  else if (num_test && mail_num.length > 13) {
    msg("The number is too large");
    formValid.mail_num_valid = false;
  }

else {
  msg("Mail not correct");
  formValid.mail_num_valid = false;
}

checkValidation();

});


$('#{{ form.name.id_for_label }}').on('input', function() {

var name = $(this).val();


function msg(content) {
  $('#name_error').text(content).show();
};

function hide() {
  $('#name_error').hide();
};

if (name.length > 2) {
  formValid.name_valid = true;
  hide();
}

else if (name.length == 0) {
  formValid.name_valid = false;
  hide();
}

else {
  msg("The name is required");
  formValid.name_valid = false;
}

checkValidation();


});
```

```html
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="fieldWrapper">

<label for="{{ form.mail_or_num.id_for_label }}">Mail/Number:</label>
{{ form.mail_or_num }}
<p id="mail_num_error"></p>
</div>


<div class="fieldWrapper">

<label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}">CC yourself?</label>
{{ form.name }}
<p id="name_error"></p>
</div>

<div class="fieldWrapper">

<label for="{{ form.message.id_for_label }}">Your message:</label>
{{ form.message }}

</div>




<input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Send message" disabled />
</form>
```